# Row selection with a condition - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to take the rows from the following table (`NEW`) that the values of the first column of the `Edge` column (i.e. `NEW.Edge(i,1)`) are equal to the certain Number (N) and the values in the second column of `Edge` column (i.e. `NEW.Edge(i,2)`) are `not equal to the values of array (IDs)`. For example, if  `N=2` and `IDs=15,20` then I should get the rows from 1 to row 9.

The code that I tried so far is :

```
Y =[];
for i = 1:size(NEW,1)
    if ((NEW.Edge(i,1)==N) & (sum(ismember(IDs,NEW.Edge(i,2))==0)))
        Y = NEW.Edge(i,1)&NEW.Edge(i,2);
    end
end
```

And

```
Y = ((NEW.Edge(i,1)==N) & (sum(ismember(IDs,NEW.Edge(i,2))==0)))
Lines = NEW (Y,:)
```

----Table 'NEW'

```
  Event      Node      Edge  
_________    ____    ________

edgetonew    NaN      2     6
edgetonew    NaN      2     7
edgetonew    NaN      2     8
edgetonew    NaN      2     9
edgetonew    NaN      2    10
edgetonew    NaN      2    11
edgetonew    NaN      2    12
edgetonew    NaN      2    13
edgetonew    NaN      2    14
edgetonew    NaN      2    15
edgetonew    NaN     15    16
edgetonew    NaN     15    17
edgetonew    NaN     15    18
edgetonew    NaN     15    19
edgetonew    NaN     15    20
edgetonew    NaN     20    21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ismember` and logical indexing to accomplish this. `ismember` will return a boolean array the size of the first input that is `true` if each value in the first input is *anywhere* in the second.

```
% Will be TRUE when the first column == N and the second column isn't in IDs
rows_to_keep = NEW.Edge(:,1) == N & ~ismember(NEW.Edge(:,2), IDs);

% Now use this logical array to grab just the rows that satisfy the condition
out = NEW(rows_to_keep,:);
```